# PHPUnit color bars not showing on Windows 10

Tags: php, windows, phpunit

My PHPUnit tests output does not show colored bars (green /red) on Windows 10:

[image]

I already tried:

1) Installing [ansicon](https://superuser.com/questions/208150/phpunit-windows-command-box-nice-colors);

2) Changing to older versions of PHPUnit (like 4.7.1 as in the screenshot above)

And I am using  colors="true" as you can see in phpunit.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit colors="true">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Application Test Suite">
            <directory>./tests/</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

Any other ideas?
Thanks!